# Can't access to my variable r

Tags: r, shiny

I am actually on a shiny app. Here is my code.

**global.R**

```
json <- fromJSON("./init.json")
param <- json$cube %>% setDT()
global <- list()
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$chargerCube,{
    startLoading()
    global <- creationCube(input)
    endLoading()
  })

  observeEvent(input$butAddCol,{
    global <- ajoutColonne(global, input)
  })  
})
```

My problem is that in my second observeEvent, i have the error that my "global" variable doesn't exist ... I don't understand why :/

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
source('global.R')
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
      observeEvent(input$chargerCube,{
        startLoading()
        global <- creationCube(input)
        endLoading()
      })

      observeEvent(input$butAddCol,{
        global <- ajoutColonne(global, input)
      })  
    })
```